# How to implement a chatbot to human executive switch using Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

The exact point being, that I've created a bot that can take inputs from users in free form text and return relevant web links. Now the problem being, that in case the bot is not able to understand the user query, the control of the conversation has to be passed on to the human executive.
I've researched for over 2 days but could not find any such implementations. The closest I came was third party applications like ChatFuel, letsclap.io provide such a provision. So, there should be a way only that I am not able to find such a thing.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there interface for Human agent in Microsoft Bot Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882378/is-there-interface-for-human-agent-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

one possible way is you can make a **bridge**, idea is as follow:

1. user send something that the bot cannot reply (conv-1)
2. make a new conversation with your human executive (conv-2)
3. forward user message to conv-2
4. human executive replied to the bot (conv-2)
5. capture the message and forward back to (conv-1)

**See this link on how to start a new conversation**:

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#sendtoconversation

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for the reply. @kienct89
But it also involves stopping messages to the underlying LUIS framework that is interpreting the messages. How can this happen?
I am stuck at this point of implementing as the the bot kicks in before the human can respond and it ultimately creates a confusion for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create some APIs in a WebApplication that will be used by your bot. 
If the LUIS Intent "None" is called, you make a call to that API and start a new conversation with a human.

You can use this same process to manage all conversations in a WebApplication Chat Control