# Connecting to a human interface

Tags: botframework

I am trying to develop a bot with the botframework. I am trying to use Luis for a semantic analysis when it comes to a generic question. But in case I do not the specification that even luis cannot answer i want to transfer the control to a human interface. Is there anyway botframework can do this?

Comment: this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012107/how-to-implement-a-chatbot-to-human-executive-switch-using-microsoft-bot-framewo/39033551#39033551

Comment: Just another idea in addition to the above, maybe start a group conversation with the bot, user and human? Also set some flag in the user's BotData so that the bot knows he needs to ignore all subsequent messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there interface for Human agent in Microsoft Bot Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882378/is-there-interface-for-human-agent-in-microsoft-bot-framework)