# Is there interface for Human agent in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

Good day!

Does any one know if there is interface for Human agent in Microsoft Bot Framework?

I need to forward dialog to real agent in case if visitor can't get answer with my bot.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3 different channels in the same conversation botframework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200249/3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework)

Answer (score 2):

There are samples that solve this specific problem:

- For Node.js: https://github.com/palindromed/Bot-HandOff
- For C#: https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

I have plans to publish the C# solution as a Nuget package as soon as it gets mature enough, but at the moment you can just copy the code (and modify to suit your needs) from the repo to your project.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Tomi

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything built-in for a human to reply as your bot in Bot Framework.

You could make your own interface and hook it up to the Bot Connector via Direct Line

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/