# How to disconnect LUIS of Microsoft Bot Connector selectively?

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Keeping a human executive at stand by to answer user queries is a critical use case for the chat bot I am developing.
But I am not able to figure out how to handover control to the human agent without the NLP mode (LUIS) not getting disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (might not be suitable for your scenario though) is overriding the MessageReceived of your LuisDialog and add there the logic to decide if the query will go to LUIS or not. That's probably the easiest part of the story :)

Another thing to resolve will be how to handover the control. This was discussed in threads here in SO and in GitHub:

- [How to implement a chatbot to human executive switch using Microsoft Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012107/how-to-implement-a-chatbot-to-human-executive-switch-using-microsoft-bot-framewo/39033551#39033551)
- [Transfer the chat control to a human chat executive.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1106)
- [Escalate to human](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/169)

For an idea of how to create new conversations, you can check the [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-CreateNewConversation) and  [Node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-CreateNewConversation) samples.